# Why can't you end a while loop with a label?

Tags: c++, goto

Instead of writing

```
while()
{
 lbl:
}
```

You have to write

```
while()
{
 lbl:;
}
```

Why? It doesn't make any sort of sense to me. This is the case even if there was actual code in the loop

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with the `while`. For example: `{label:;}`.

Comment: Essentially:   because a label is an optional part of a statement, and the statement needs to be a complete statement.  A label followed by `:` on its own is not a complete statement.     `;` is an indicator of the end of a statement.     The rule helps the compiler parse sensibly, since it can unambiguously recognise the beginning and end of each individual statement (e.g.  by presence of `;` or, in the case of block statements, the `{` and matching `}`).

Answer (score -1):

If you code in C, because the C11 standard defines that. Check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §6.8.1. BTW, other standards of C have a similar rule.

If you code in C++, **because the C++11 standard defines that**. Check by reading [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), §6.1. BTW, other standards of C++ have a similar rule.

Intuitively, a label concerns a *statement*, and the closing brace is not a statement (but a block terminator). And a semi-colon (when used alone) is ending an empty (or null) statement.

If you are not happy with that rule, feel free to use some different programming language, or to define your own one (and implement it, perhaps by [compiling it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) to C). Maybe you could look into [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme) (read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) then [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/)) and its [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) primitive (a different, and more powerful, control primitive than plain [`goto`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto)).

You could also lobby the C++ (or C) standard committee to change the rules. In practice, that requires a world-wide reputation and many years of full time work (otherwise, they won't consider your proposal seriously). Before writing proposals to change the C++ standard, be sure to learn it very well and to provide a sample implementation of your ideas.

Many C++ implementations are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)). You are allowed to study them and to improve them (at least in your [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)); however be sure to comply with their [open-source license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_license)). However, there are large pieces of code (many millions lines of source code), so you'll need years to understand them.

Remember that a programming language is a specification (not a software) which defines not only the [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)) but also the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)).